# How to add images containing database with them

Tags: android, gridview

I am having a gridview which consist of "add" button for adding a new kid in gridview.When I click on "add" button new registration form gets opened.The form is related to kid`s information(kid (pk),fname,lname,gender,email,phone no,uploadphoto).User has to fill the form related to his kid.If user doesn`t have his kid`s photo then default image(either male or female) should be added in gridview.How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply add view to adapter by

```
adapter.add(Object item)
```

in this method pass oject which you is returned by getItem method.